# Creating a Verizon CDN endpoint through Azure using Terraform that disables caching

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Is it possible to disable caching when you create the Verizon CDN endpoint using Terraform? I am trying to configure the caching settings similar to how its configured here in the GUI.

[image]

Unfortunately, when using the `Standard_Verizon` SKU, you can't use the `global_delivery_rule` and `delivery_rule` blocks as they are not applicable to Verizon endpoints.

Is there anyway I can disable caching or am I stuck with disabling them in the GUI after the endpoint has been created?

Answer (score 0):

global_delivery_rule and delivery_rule are currently only available for Microsoft_Standard CDN profiles.

When tried to set up caching rules with standard_verizon :

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_profile" "example" {
  name                = "examplestdcdn"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Standard_Verizon"
}
resource "azurerm_cdn_profile" "examplen" {
  name                = "stdnexamplekacdn"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Standard_Microsoft"
}

resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "cdn_endpoint_standard" {
  name                = "stnd-cdn-endpoint"
  profile_name        = azurerm_cdn_profile.examplen.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  origin {
    name      = "stand-cdn-origin"
    host_name = "standardexampl.com"
  }
  
   global_delivery_rule {
    cache_expiration_action {
       behavior = "BypassCache"
      
    }
   }

  delivery_rule {
    name  = "cachegeneratedfiles"
    order = 1
    url_file_extension_condition {
      operator = "Any" 
      # match_values = ["css", "js"]
      transforms = ["Lowercase"]
    }
    cache_expiration_action {
      behavior = "BypassCache"
     
    }
  }

  querystring_caching_behaviour = "IgnoreQueryString"
  is_http_allowed        = false
  is_compression_enabled = true

  content_types_to_compress = ["text/plain", "application/json"]




}
```

Creating with standard_verizon and then changing the portal gives the error as   they are not applicable.

**Error occurred:**

[image]

```
│ Error: expanding `global_delivery_rule` or `delivery_rule`: Cache expiration duration must not be set when using behavior `BypassCache`
│
│   with azurerm_cdn_endpoint.cdn_endpoint_standard
```

Add ignore_changes .

```
lifecycle {
ignore_changes = [
global_delivery_rule,
delivery_rule
]
}
```

Following caching rules are set using Standard_Microsoft  sku .

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_profile" "examplen" {
  name                = "stdnexamplekacdn"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Standard_Microsoft"
}

resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "cdn_endpoint" {
  name                = "stnd-cdn-endpoint"
  profile_name        = azurerm_cdn_profile.examplen.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  origin {
    name      = "stand-cdn-origin"
    host_name = "standardexampl.com"
  }
  
   global_delivery_rule {
     cache_expiration_action {
       behavior = "BypassCache"
      
     }
  }

  delivery_rule {
    name  = "cachegeneratedfiles"
    order = 1
    url_file_extension_condition {
      operator = "Any"       
      transforms = ["Lowercase"]
    }
    cache_expiration_action {
      behavior = "BypassCache"
     
    }
  }

  querystring_caching_behaviour = "IgnoreQueryString"
  is_http_allowed        = false
  is_compression_enabled = true

  content_types_to_compress = ["text/plain", "application/json", "application/x-javascript", "text/html", "text/css"]



}
```

[image]

[image]

Refer to this is an ongoing issue in [Github : [azurerm_cdn_endpoint] Standard_Verizon global_delivery_rule and delivery_rule support](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8511)